# apt-get install wine-stable tries to remove half my system packages

Tags: apt, wine

I have ubuntu 18.04

```
sudo apt-get install wine-stable
```

when I run this apt-get tries to remove half my system packages.

```
The following additional packages will be installed:
  fonts-wine libcapi20-3 libnginx-mod-http-auth-pam libnginx-mod-http-dav-ext libnginx-mod-http-echo libnginx-mod-http-subs-filter libnginx-mod-http-upstream-fair
  libodbc1 libopenal-data libopenal1 libwine nginx-full wine64
Suggested packages:
  libmyodbc odbc-postgresql tdsodbc unixodbc-bin libportaudio2 ttf-mscorefonts-installer nginx-doc winbind winetricks playonlinux wine-binfmt dosbox
  libwine-gecko-2.47 wine64-preloader
Recommended packages:
  libosmesa6 wine32
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  aisleriot baobab bluez-cups bluez-obexd brltty cuda cuda-10-1 cuda-nsight-10-1 cuda-nvvp-10-1 cuda-toolkit-10-1 cuda-tools-10-1 cuda-visual-tools-10-1 deja-dup
  discord eog evince file-roller firefox flatpak fwupd gdm3 gedit gir1.2-gmenu-3.0 gnome-bluetooth gnome-calendar gnome-disk-utility gnome-font-viewer
  gnome-initial-setup gnome-mahjongg gnome-mines gnome-screensaver gnome-screenshot gnome-software gnome-software-plugin-snap gnome-sudoku gnome-todo gnuplot-qt
  gstreamer1.0-packagekit gstreamer1.0-plugins-base-apps gstreamer1.0-tools gtk2-engines-murrine gvfs-fuse hardinfo libdazzle-1.0-0 libedataserverui-1.2-2
  libevdocument3-4 libevview3-3 libgnome-menu-3-0 libgraphene-1.0-0 libgxps2 libinput-tools libmagickcore-6.q16-3-extra libopenjfx-java libopenjfx-jni
  libpoppler-glib8 libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer libreoffice-gnome libreoffice-gtk3 libspice-server1 libxcb-xv0 light-themes lightdm linux-generic-hwe-18.04
  linux-headers-4.18.0-15-generic linux-headers-5.0.0-23-generic linux-headers-generic-hwe-18.04 mongodb-database-tools mongodb-mongosh mongodb-org
  mongodb-org-database mongodb-org-mongos mongodb-org-server mongodb-org-shell mongodb-org-tools nautilus nautilus-share nginx-core nodejs openjfx plymouth-label
  plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo postgresql postgresql-10 postgresql-contrib pulseaudio pulseaudio-module-bluetooth pulseaudio-utils python-cairo python-cryptography
  python-gi-cairo python-keyring python-secretstorage python3-gi-cairo python3-pyudev qemu-kvm qemu-system-x86 sbsigntool secureboot-db shotwell simple-scan
  terminator thermald thunderbird thunderbird-gnome-support totem totem-plugins transmission-gtk ubuntu-artwork ubuntu-desktop ubuntu-software unity-greeter
  unity-settings-daemon vino whoopsie xorg xserver-xephyr xserver-xorg-input-wacom-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-video-ati-hwe-18.04
  xserver-xorg-video-qxl-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-video-radeon-hwe-18.04
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  fonts-wine libcapi20-3 libnginx-mod-http-auth-pam libnginx-mod-http-dav-ext libnginx-mod-http-echo libnginx-mod-http-subs-filter libnginx-mod-http-upstream-fair
  libodbc1 libopenal-data libopenal1 libwine nginx-full wine-stable wine64
0 upgraded, 14 newly installed, 121 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Comment: Did you do an sudo update and a sudo upgrade before trying to install Wine? You should have.

Comment: Yes I did, says 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Comment: Well it is not half the system packages. It seems you have a lot of old stuff on your system.

Comment: yeah true but its trying to remove totally unrelated stuff like firefox, cuda-toolkit and postgresql and also other things which I suspect will break the system like pulseaudio, gnome stuff and ubuntu-software

Comment: Old versions of them?

Comment: I think they're the current ones I'm using. Is there a way to check?

Comment: Firefox is easy just look at the about or help.

Comment: I dont understand. I'm fairly certain I have only one version of firefox installed? Sorry I'm not really that good at this

Comment: Please add output of `apt-cache policy wine-stable wine64 wine32 libwine` to the question.